# react bootstrap custom tab not working

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi I am trying to use custom tab from React-Bootstrap. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#tabs

The error I am getting is

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method
```

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tab,Row,Col,Nav,NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';


export default class ControlledTabs extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <Tab.Container id="left-tabs-example" defaultActiveKey="first">
        <Row className="clearfix">
          <Col sm={4}>
            <Nav bsStyle="pills" stacked>
              <NavItem eventKey="first">
                Tab 1
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey="second">
                Tab 2
              </NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Col>
          <Col sm={8}>
            <Tab.Content animation>
              <Tab.Pane eventKey="first">
                Tab 1 content
              </Tab.Pane>
              <Tab.Pane eventKey="second">
                Tab 2 content
              </Tab.Pane>
            </Tab.Content>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Tab.Container>

    );
  }
}
```

Please let me know what I have done wrong, thanks

Comment: looks alright. this error happens when the import failed due to some reason.

Comment: yeah I have already explored that possibility. for eg import { component} vs import component etc. I still cant find the solution.

Comment: `TabContainer` maybe?

Comment: Try to `console.error(!!Tab.Container, ...` to see which one is false

Comment: What version of react-bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I did console.error(!!Tab.Container) which returned false. Tested console.error(!!Tab) which returned true. The culprit is Tab.Container, Tab.Pane and anything else with a dot. The question now is how do I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Yes did npm cache clean. Version "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.1"

Comment: @mtangula how did you solve this?